# If condition is met then do the following

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm struggling with creating a query and was hoping to get some guidance from those wiser than me.  I'm trying to write a query such that when DRG Code = 005, then take all of the HOSP_ADMT_DT from this query and then query the general claims table again without the DRG = 5 condition and pull all claims that are 30 days or before the admit date and 180 days or less after the admit date and then join the results.

Edit:
The result I'm looking for would run the query below.  I need this result.  And then take all of the Member ID's and and Admit dates resulting from the query below and execute a query that Pulls all of the original fields without the DRG criteria = 005, but criteria on member id's that had DRG 5 and admit date and then pull all claims from this subset and the pull all claims in range Admit Date (defined by:HOSP_ADMT_DT)  - 30 and Admit Date + 180. CLM_LN_SVC_FROM_DT
           ,CLM_LN_SVC_TO_DT - Defined by

```
SELECT CLM_MED_DETL_ID
       ,CLM_ID_TXT
       ,CLM_SRC_CD
       ,CLM_LN_SEQ_NUM
       ,MBR_ID
       ,MBR_LST_NAME
       ,MBR_FST_NAME
       ,SVCG_PROV_ADDR_ZIP_CD
       ,SVCG_PROV - ADDR_CNTY
       ,SBMTD_DRG_CD
       ,HOSP_ADMT_DT
       ,HOSP_DSCHRG_DT
       ,RVNU_CD
       ,CLM_LN_UNITS_NUM
       ,CLM_LN_CHRG_AMT
       ,CLM_LN_ALWD_AMT
       ,CLM_LN_PD_AMT
       ,TIN_TXT
       ,HOSP_ADMT_DT
       ,CLM_LN_SVC_FROM_DT
       ,CLM_LN_SVC_TO_DT
    FROM CLM_MED_DETL
    WHERE TIN_TXT IN ( 'A', 'B' )
        AND SBMTD_DRG_CD = '005'
        AND CLM_SRC_CD = 'TRG_FA'
    ORDER BY MBR_LST_NAME ASC
       ,CLM_LN_SEQ_NUM ASC;
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired results (by editing your question).

Comment: It's hard for me to add data on this one.  Essentially I would like to run query 1 and then take the member id's (have DRG 5) and admit date and then run a query with these two conditionals mbr id in(x1,x2,xn) and when mbr id matches use there admit date and subtract 30 and add 180 to the CLM LN SVC FROM DT and pull all claims not just DRG 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

... `WHERE (SBMTD_DRG_CD='005' OR  (SBMTD_DRG_CD <>'005 AND (claim is > 30 days OR  laim.date < (180 + admit.date)) ))`

I don't know how your dates are stored.
(Sorry,writing on phone,can't format code)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  The only problem with this is it can't be an or condition.  I think it must be some form of sub query.  Query get result, take certain elements of result and use and criteria in sub query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need smth like this:

- the `CD_005` subquery returns the medical details for DRG criteria = 005, I've also included your additional conditions there, you may want to amend them
- And the `CD_ANY` alias contains all the records from that table

When we join these aliases on `MBR_ID` and `HOSP_ADMT_DT` range, we receive all the records within [-30;+180] dates range around '005' claim for the clients who ever had '005' claim.

```
WITH CD_005 as (
    SELECT  MBR_ID, HOSP_ADMT_DT
        FROM CLM_MED_DETL
        WHERE TIN_TXT IN ( 'A', 'B' )
            AND SBMTD_DRG_CD = '005'
            AND CLM_SRC_CD = 'TRG_FA'
)
SELECT CLM_MED_DETL_ID
       ,CLM_ID_TXT
       ,CLM_SRC_CD
       ,CLM_LN_SEQ_NUM
       ,CD_ANY.MBR_ID
       ,MBR_LST_NAME
       ,MBR_FST_NAME
       ,SVCG_PROV_ADDR_ZIP_CD
       ,SVCG_PROV - ADDR_CNTY
       ,SBMTD_DRG_CD
       ,CD_ANY.HOSP_ADMT_DT
       ,HOSP_DSCHRG_DT
       ,RVNU_CD
       ,CLM_LN_UNITS_NUM
       ,CLM_LN_CHRG_AMT
       ,CLM_LN_ALWD_AMT
       ,CLM_LN_PD_AMT
       ,TIN_TXT
       ,HOSP_ADMT_DT
       ,CLM_LN_SVC_FROM_DT
       ,CLM_LN_SVC_TO_DT
   FROM CLM_MED_DETL CD_ANY 
   JOIN CD_005 
     on CD_ANY.MBR_ID = CD_005.MBR_ID 
    and CD_ANY.HOSP_ADMT_DT >= CD_005.HOSP_ADMT_DT -  30
    and CD_ANY.HOSP_ADMT_DT <= CD_005.HOSP_ADMT_DT + 180
  ORDER BY MBR_LST_NAME ASC
       ,CLM_LN_SEQ_NUM ASC;
```

Hope it runs well and really helps, I just can't check it as I don't have such tables.